# html form with dhtml fade effects

Tags: jquery, dhtml, fade

i am trying to implement an html form with this dhtml fade effects: http://dhtmlpopups.webarticles.org/fade-effects.php

but i got no luck. 
-i included a jquery validation in the fade effect, and when the user is entering values for the form, the pop-up times out, and when i redirect to "success page", i am pretty much unable to click anywhere on the page.

has anyone successfully implemented html form in a dhtml/fade effect, can you please give a hand? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just show/hide the div with [$.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) and $.fadeOut()?

Answer (score 0):

fadeIn and fadeOut accept 2 parameters. The 1st the time of fading in miliminute, 2nd a call back function that will be fired after fading. You could set the 1st parameter larger, say 3000. Check compact script for fading,

http://www.pagecolumn.com/javascript/fade.htm